# Create window in screen size in wpf

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

I create a window in wpf and in xml file I write this code:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid >

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

But when I run the project, the size of window is 1080*625. I expect the window size become the screen size, but isn't. Why?

Comment: Have you tried setting `WindowState="Maximized"` on Window?

Comment: No, I don't. But I want to know what is wrong with my code.

Comment: So set it and see if that works.

Comment: It works,But in my code why 1080*625?

Comment: I guess that's default size of WPF window. Not sure though.

Comment: It is a Window not a form

Answer (score 3):

You need to set `WindowState` to `Maximmized`:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" WindowState="Maximized"/>
```